# NgRx createSelector always wrapps the state

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have created a very simple state management for my Angular 16 Standalone app.

Everything works fine. I can dispatch new values and select. Also the Redux dev-tools browser plugin shows me the correct formatting of the layout in the store (`{ app: { layout: 'full' } }`).

I am just puzzeled about the automated wrapping of the state in the selectors.
The wrapping is happening somewhere while reading from the store.

I would expect that i can do
`createSelector(getAppState, (app: AppState) => app);`
instead of
`createSelector(getAppState, (app: any) => app.app);`

where is my mistake?

app.state.ts:

```
import { Selector } from "@ngrx/store";

export type Layout = "full" | "sidebar" | "center";

export interface AppState {
  layout: Layout;
}

export const initialState: AppState = {
  layout: "full",
};

export const getAppState: Selector<AppState, AppState> = (state) => state;
```

app.selectors.ts (containing the strange bahvior):

```
import { createSelector } from "@ngrx/store";
import { getAppState } from "@store/app/app.state";

// app is wrapped like { app: app } so i need to use 'any' and return app.app 
const getLayoutState = createSelector(getAppState, (app: any) => app.app);

// layout is wrapped like { layout: layout } so i need to use 'any' and return layout.layout
export const selectLayout = createSelector(
  getLayoutState,
  (layout: any) => layout.layout
);
```

app.reducers.ts

```
import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { setLayout } from "@store/app/app.actions";
import { AppState, initialState } from "@store/app/app.state";

export const appReducers = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(setLayout, (state: AppState, { layout }) => ({
    ...state,
    layout,
  }))
);
```

main.ts:

```
[...]
providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideStore({ app: appReducers }),
  ],
[...]
```

Comment: simple asnwer is - use ngrx schematics to add ngrx and create feature states. everything will look waayy better and would work flawlessly

Comment: the schematics do not work well with angular standalone because they base on ngModules. i played around a bit with the schematics and i disagree on the point that the result looks better. it is actually pretty similar to what i have just lacks directory structure and a facade. Still many thanks for pointing me at the schematics! Sadly that did not brought me further with my problem.